# nginx server, multiple users editing their own files via SFTP

Tags: nginx, permissions

I'd like to have a Debian server set up so that different users have their own domains that only they can edit, e.g.:

```
/home/
+ /bob/www/
    + oldsocks.com/
    + nosepickers.org/
+ /joe/www/
    + no-fun.com/
    + whatever.net/
```

Bob should be able to SFTP in and edit his stuff, and likewise for Joe. The problem, of course, is that nginx and php-fpm run as `www-data`. With Apache, I was able to install the `apache-mpm-itk` package and use the `AssignUserID` directive to make each virtual host have its own uid/gid. I don't think any such thing exists for nginx.

I'm not experienced enough to know of a good way to set up the above structure that works with nginx. I suppose I'll have to settle for all files being owned by `www-data` and find some way to lock each SFTP user to their own `www` folder (ssh jail?). I'm open to suggestions.

Side note: Ideally, each user would be locked into their `www` folder when SFTP'ing in, but not SSH'ing in. Don't know if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solutions is to use ProFTPd with mod_sftp like this:

```
SFTPEngine on
SFTPLog /var/log/sftp.log
Port 2222
SFTPHostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
SFTPHostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
SFTPCompression delayed
MaxLoginAttempts 6
DefaultRoot ~
Umask 002
CreateHome on 770 dirmode 770
```

And change joe's and bob's user group to `www-data`.
So your web server will be able to access files because they are `www-data` group readable and writable. `DefaultRoot` will jail users inside their home directories, all newly created files and folders will have `www-data` group.

Comment: Great, so far so good! Except when I sftp in and create a file, it's owned by `bob:bob`, not `bob:www-data`. I did `sudo addgroup bob www-data` and even tried to make it his primary group via `sudo usermod -g www-data bob` but neither worked.

Comment: Ah, got it. Had to set the folder's group sticky bit (`sudo chmod g+s domainfolder.com`).

Comment: You added bob to the `www-data` group. What I suggested is to change his primary group `usermod -g www-data bob` then all files he create will have `bob:www-data`. But your approach seems to work too.

Comment: I tried `usermod -g www-data bob`, and files created by bob are still owned by `bob:bob`. When I realized this didn't work, I tried the group sticky bit.